# Equals operator on STL vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl

I have 2 vectors, with the type of a pointer to Point to take advantage of polymorphism idea, because I have some type of points classes that inherit from the Point class.

```
vector<Point*> previous_points;
vector<Point*> current_points;

init_points(previous_points);
init_points(current_points);

do_some_proccess(previous_points);
do_some_proccess(current_points);

cout << (previous_points == current_points) << endl; // returns 0
```

the == operator returns me 0 even though the contents are the same, and the reason is (from what i read and understood) that it is comparing the vector contents which are pointers and the pointers are not the same of course (init_points creates new objects with same content for each of the vectors).

my question is, can i still use the comparison operator and get it compare the content of the pointers in my vectors and not the pointer themselves? or do i have to implement my own **is_content_equals** function to do that?

edit: I have implemented the equals == operator inside the Point class so it is comparing the content of point.

thanks

Comment: If the pointers are not the same, then the contents are not the same.

Comment: Your comparison will only compare the *pointers* in the vectors, not the objects they point to.

Comment: I have implemented the equals == operator inside the Point class so it is comparing the content. forgot to mention it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that is my question, do I need to implement my own function to do this? or I can still use the operator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to roll out your own function. You can use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal), with a suitable predicate. This assumes a working `operator==` for `Point`.

```
bool ok = equal(begin(previous_points), end(previous_points),
                begin(current_points), end(current_points),
                [](const Point* lhs, const Point* rhs){ return *lhs == * rhs; });
```

Pre C++14, you can use this overload. Here, it is up to you to ensure that `current_points` is the same length as `previous_points`.

```
bool ok = equal(begin(previous_points), end(previous_points),
                begin(current_points),
                [](const Point* lhs, const Point* rhs){ return *lhs == * rhs; });
```

Comment: Oh great, the pre c++14 overload worked for me. last question, it is up to me to ensure the length are the same, by that you mean that I need to do those 2 checks (length and content) in order to get the equals compare it efficiently as the == would do? thanks again, and I guess I need to learn more about lambda functions on c++, this is the first time I use it in this language.

Comment: @DimaGimburg Yes, that is what I mean. `std::equal` compares ranges, and the pre-C++11 only sets the beginning of the second. So two things can be different to `==`. First, the second range is longer. `==` should then be false, but the sub-range can be equal to the first subrange. Second, the second range could be shorter, in which case you go beyond bounds and get *undefined behaviour*, which is *very bad* and has to be avoided.

Comment: This _is_ rolling your own function ^_^